# What is the type of function received in props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
interface IProps {
  handleCloseModal: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
  returnFunction: () => void;
}

export default function Modal({
  children,
  returnFunction,
  handleCloseModal,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const handleToggle = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLDivElement;
    if (!ref.current?.contains(target)) {
      handleCloseModal();
    }
  };

  const handleCloseAndExcuteFn = () => {
    handleCloseModal();
    returnFunction();
  };

return (
        <section>
          <Button close onClick={handleCloseModal}>
            no
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleCloseAndExcuteFn}>yes</Button>
        </section>
  )
};
```

If you look at "handleCloseModal" in the code above,

Since it is used in 'onclick', I gave the type as 'React.MouseEventHandler'

But 'handleCloseAndExcuteFn'
Because it is also used here, a type error occurs.

What is the right type?

In addition

I'm curious about the 'returnFunction' type.
This function is

`const returnFunction = () => { logout().then(() => dispatch(setUserId(''))); };`

Same as above code, change 'redux state' after axios request.

Answer (score 1):

Move the event type to the actual function you are passing to onClick which is
handleCloseAndExcuteFn

```js
interface IProps {
  handleCloseModal: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
  returnFunction: () => void;
}

const handleCloseAndExcuteFn: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = () => {
    handleCloseModal();
    returnFunction();
};
```